# Getting FontMetrics StackOverflowError

Tags: java, fonts, awt, stack-overflow, fontmetrics

Running the following code:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;

public class MetricsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                Font myFontTest=new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 11);
                FontMetrics metrics  = new FontMetrics(myFontTest) {};
                int characterWidth=metrics.charWidth('A');
                System.out.println(characterWidth);
    }
}
```

produces this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

at java.awt.FontMetrics.getWidths(FontMetrics.java:430)

at java.awt.FontMetrics.charWidth(FontMetrics.java:333)

at java.awt.FontMetrics.getWidths(FontMetrics.java:430)

at java.awt.FontMetrics.charWidth(FontMetrics.java:333)

at java.awt.FontMetrics.getWidths(FontMetrics.java:430)

and so on....

Why?

Comment: You cannot just create a `new FontMetrics` you need to get one from _somewhere_. You are not running in the EDT and have no Swing components - the font is not being rendered so how can it have a width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution:
(see comment by user Boris the Spider) on my original post)

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;

public class MetricsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                Font myFontTest=new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 11);
                Canvas c = new Canvas();
                FontMetrics fm = c.getFontMetrics(myFontTest);
                int characterWidth=fm.charWidth('A');
                System.out.println(characterWidth);

    }

}
```

Comment: My reputation is too small to do this now. I have to wait until tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

From [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html):

> Note to subclassers: Since many of these methods form closed, mutually
>   recursive loops, you must take care that you implement at least one of
>   the methods in each such loop to prevent infinite recursion when your
>   subclass is used. In particular, the following is the minimal
>   suggested set of methods to override in order to ensure correctness
>   and prevent infinite recursion (though other subsets are equally
>   feasible):

This:

```
FontMetrics metrics  = new FontMetrics(myFontTest) {};
```

defines a subclass without any methods overridden, hence the behaviour you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your code as follows :

```
try {
    Font myFontTest=new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 11);
    Frame f = new Frame();
    //FontMetrics metrics = f.getToolkit().getFontMetrics(myFontTest);      
    FontMetrics metrics = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getFontMetrics(myFontTest);

    int characterWidth=metrics.charWidth('A');
    System.out.println(characterWidth);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Is using a Frame better that using a canvas? (see my own answer)

Comment: as per documentatioin `getToolkit().getFontMetrics(myFontTest)` is a deprecated method. But, I think it will be better if you use if it is available. refer the documentation of canvas.getFontMetrics method.